# ¿Por que esta función no devuelve los números primos hasta x?

Tags: rstudio, matemáticas

```
primos = function(x){
  p = length(x)
  i = 2
  while (i<=x){
    creciente = 2
    Primo = TRUE
    while(Primo && creciente<i)
    {
      if(i%%creciente==0){
        Primo=FALSE
      }
      else
      {
        creciente=creciente+1
      }
    }
    if(Primo==TRUE){
      print(i)
    }
  }
```

Hola, este algoritmo debería devolver los números primos hasta llegar al numero que inserir por teclado? Algo pasa, pero creo que no debería pasar nada mal. Si alguien puede decir donde esta el error... Gracias. Saludos.

Comment: @LázaroMER Lo siento, pero no sé que lenguaje es la mas correcta en la verdade, porque es la usada RStudio.

Comment: Si trabajas en RStudio a lo mejor estas haciendo uso del lenguaje R

Comment: Si, es lenguaje R.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Porque tu variable `i` nunca cambia y sólo hace la verificación con el 2, agrega un incremento después de tu `if(Primo==TRUE){...}` sobre la variable `i`:

```
if(Primo==TRUE){
    print(i)
}
i=i+1
```

Comment: Eso de ser principiante en algo es una cosa... JAJA, era eso